# Upgrading angular from 4.0.0-beta.5 to 4.0.0 breaks animations and unit tests

Tags: angular

I have upgraded angular packages in my app from 4.0.0-beta.5 to 4.0.0 and I see the following error when I run my unit tests:

> Error: Found the synthetic property @transition. Please include either  "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.

Then I installed @angular/animations 4.0.0 and included BrowserAnimationsModule in the app module as I use animations.

Now I notice that animations work but tests fail with the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the issue, some of the tests were using angular Testbed

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule, NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   imports: [
      RouterTestingModule,
      ...,
      BrowserAnimationsModule // Added this or NoopAnimationsModule** to fix it 
   ]
```

> NOTE**: you can also use NoopAnimationsModule instead if you don't want animations in your tests which is typically the case